# Android studio monitor.exe exits with an error and asks to check log file

Tags: android-studio

```
!SESSION 2018-03-05 08:35:32.171 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_80
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -data @noDefault

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-03-05 08:35:57.121
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-03-05 08:35:57.135
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.jasper.glassfish_2.2.2.v201205150955.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-03-05 08:35:57.142
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.lucene.core_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-03-05 08:35:57.219
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.base_3.6.101.v201302041200.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-03-05 08:35:57.224
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.ui_3.5.201.v20130108-092756.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-03-05 08:35:57.234
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.webapp_3.6.101.v20130116-182509.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-03-05 08:35:57.241
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.jetty.server_8.1.3.v20120522.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-03-05 08:35:57.259
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.platform.doc.user_4.2.2.v20130121-200410.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-03-05 08:35:57.266
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.team.core_3.6.100.v20120524-0627.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-03-05 08:35:57.275
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.team.ui_3.6.201.v20130125-135424.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-03-05 08:35:57.282
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets_3.4.200.v20120521-2344.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-03-05 08:35:57.291
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.ui.intro_3.4.200.v20120521-2344.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2018-03-05 08:36:04.574
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor (5).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor.MonitorPlugin for bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor is invalid
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
    at
```

// I'm not still relatively new to computer science and not sure about what all these missing bundles are. I'm currently using java jdk7. The same error is thrown when i try to launch ANDROID DEVICE MONITOR